# MUI Popover - How to start transition from mouse position?

Tags: material-ui

I want a Material UI `Popover` to open/close on mouse press, with the opening transition starting from the location of the mouse when the mouse was pressed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `anchorReference` to `anchorPosition` and then use the mouse coordinate for anchor position. So you will need to manage mouse position using state:

```js
      const [mouseX, setMouseX] = useState();
      const [mouseY, setMouseY] = useState();
```

then in your click handler set the states:

```js
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
        setMouseX(event.clientX);
        setMouseY(event.clientY);
      }
```

and finally in your jsx use mouse position in `anchorPosition`:

```js
        return (
        <div>
          <Button aria-describedby={id} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
            Open Popover
          </Button>
          <Popover
            id={id}
            anchorReference="anchorPosition"
            anchorPosition={{ top: mouseY, left: mouseX }}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: "top",
              horizontal: "left",
            }}
          >
            <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
          </Popover>
        </div>
      );
```